# Determine average and maximum execution time of a task by using ftrace/perf

Tags: linux, process, scheduling, perf, tracing

I've gathered some traces containing scheduling events ('sched:*') by using `ftrace` and `perf record`. By analyzing the results many of my questions could already be answered.

However, I was wondering if there is a practical way to use the results of ftrace or perf to determine the average execution time of a process and its maximum execution time before the respective process is blocked or preempted.

The output of `perf script` contains timestamps of the collected events but I cannot find an option to easily analyze time intervals like the time between wakeup and preemption/blocking...